# Interval y progressbar

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un metodo que me devuelve 500k resultados y me gustaria implementar una barra de progreso.

app.js

```
let test = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Start")
  this.results = calculate(type)    -> este método puede tardar 1 segundo o 5 minutos
  console.log("End")
  if (this.results.length >= 500000) {
    clearInterval(test);
  } else {
    this.progressBar = (this.results.length/500000) * 100
  }
}, 1000);
```

calculate.js

```
async calculate = function(type) {
  ......
  return calltootherlibrary(type);
}
```

Pero el problema es que entra al método, veo por consola  "Entra" y ya cuando termina de hacer el método calculate puedo ver en consola "End", es decir, la variable progressbar nunca se refresca porque espera que termine el método "calculate"

Comment: El método calculate bloquea la interfaz, no es asíncrono. ¿Puedes poner su código aquí?

Comment: Puedes echar un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187439/por-qu%c3%a9-en-un-evento-jquery-de-javascript-el-tiempo-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n-de-la-primera/187470#187470

Comment: @PabloLozano he añadido el método calculate, que esta dentro de una libreria javascript externa que uso en mi proyecto

Comment: El problema es que si ese método se está ejecutando de manera síncrona, hasta que no termine no permite al intervalo ejecutarse

Comment: @PabloLozano acabo de cambiar la pregunta por si se te ocurre algo

Comment: Tienes que crear un worker para el cálculo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers